# JaCoCo coverage parameters on SONAR

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I have a question regarding JaCoCo covergare report been published on SONAR.

When I run sonar:sonar, what I observe on the sonar server is that the coverage report only shows the "line coverage".

But the jacoco documentation and the forums say that JaCoCo can show "branch coverage, line coverage, method coverage, class coverage, complexity, instructions coverage"

In order to see the above mentioned coverage parameters, what am I supposed to include and where?

Please help. Would be of great help as I am preparing some comparisons for code analysis and unit test coverage.

Comment: Hi everyone, please help me with the above query..

Comment: I do confirm that by default when using JaCoCo, branch coverage is also computed and displayed. What is your SonarQube version ?

Comment: I use Sonarqube 4.3.1. Please also suggest regarding the other coverage parameters.

Comment: may be your project has no if-else conditions, so branch coverage is useless